# Highlight date in WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Calendar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am using  WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Calendar in windows 8.1 phone app and can display the calendar using following code:

```
<Page...
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
xmlns:wpcontrols="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls">

<Grid>
    <Viewbox>
        <wpcontrols:Calendar 
            x:Name="Cal"
            />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

And in the .cs file I set the display date by using following code in OnNavigatedTo

```
Cal.DisplayDate = new DateTime(2015, 7, 7);
```

But I cannot highlight this date and if anybody has used this control could you please give me some advise on how to set and highlight the selected date?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I had to set the following to get the date hhighlighted:

```
Cal.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2015, 6, 7);
```

Comment: How to highlight multiple dates? for example holidays?